# Div side by side within parent overflow hidden?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have 3 rows of divs wrapped in a parent div that scrolls horizontally.

I need help to show 2 rows on landscape view.

I have tried to target the last row and make it inline with the 2nd one.  I tried, inline-flex/block, left float – none of have worked.

Here is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/agipeeli/g1end453/1/

Code:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 450px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wrapper .row-container {
  padding: 20px 0 0;
  display: flex;
}

.post {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
  #wrapper {
    background-color: lightblue;
    /* flex-direction: row; - combines all 3 containers into 1 row */
  }
  .row-container:last-of-type {
    border: 1px solid green;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class='post'>Post 1</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 2</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 3</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 4</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 5</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class='post'>Post 7</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 8</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 9</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 10</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 11</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 12</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class='post'>Post 13</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 14</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 15</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 16</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 17</div>
    <div class='post'>Post 18</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you want just upper 2 rows in landscape?

Comment: ideally yes, I am open to any suggestions even if it involves using JS.

Comment: Did you want this? [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/ek0um8k0/)

Comment: thanks Asif, but your demo still shows 3 rows.  I would like to show 2 rows on landscape.

Comment: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asif92/ek0um8k0/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this? you may need to do fine-tuning, skipped the media query part.

CSS:

```
#main {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    -webkit-flex-flow: row-reverse wrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
}

#main div {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
  <div>D</div>
  <div>E</div>
  <div>F</div>
</div>
```